# Is there a way to get text from windows/classes other than Win32 WM_GetText

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there a .net namespace or similar/simpler way to get text from windows and child classes (controls) other than using a Win32 API messages?

I think there is a way to get the handle of the active window in .net without WinAPI.  Anyone know what namespace/class does that?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a .net namespace or similar/simpler way to get text from windows and child classes (controls) other than using a Win32 API messages?

You can use the [`GetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520.aspx) API, which is a bit easier than sending a `WM_GETTEXT` message. But this will only work for a window, not a for a control inside a window.

> I think there is a way to get the handle of the active window in .net without WinAPI. Anyone know what namespace/class does that?

I don't think there is anything like that in the framework. You can, however, retrieve the handle to the main window of a process, using the [`Process.MainWindowHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle.aspx) property

Comment: I found this "Microsoft Win32 to Microsoft .NET Framework API map at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302340.aspx

It looks like it's close but not quite.  I basically need a reverse-sendkeys.  Looks like listening for WM_GetText with User32.dll is the only way -- I found plenty of code samples for that.